# Proving limit to infinity using epsilon - N definition

Tags: calculus, limits

So I'm practicing with proving limits at infinity using $\epsilon$-$N$ definition. And I ran into this question in my textbook: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-3}{3x-1}=\frac{1}{3}$$
So far I have: $$\left\vert\frac{x-3}{3x-1} - \frac{1}{3}\right\vert = \left\vert\frac{-8}{9x-3}\right\vert  < \epsilon \quad\Rightarrow\quad x > \frac{8}{9\epsilon} + \frac{1}{3} = N$$
and I am not sure how to proceed at this point. Can someone clarify the next steps? Thanks.

Comment: You are are basically done.  I however am a *bear* that you put you implication arrows in the meaningful direction so that the statements you make actually mean something.  $|\frac {-8}{9x-3}|<\epsilon \Leftarrow x > N > \frac 8{9\epsilon} + \frac 13$ and you are done.... to wit: For any $\epsilon > 0$, Let $N > \frac 8{9\epsilon} + \frac 13$ then $x > N\implies 0 < \frac 1\epsilon  < \frac {9x-3}8 \implies 0 < \frac {8}{9x-3}=|\frac {-8}{9x-3}| = |\frac {x-3}{3x-1} -\frac 13| < \epsilon $.  And that is the very definition of $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac {x-3}{3x-1} = \frac 13$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\left|\frac8{9x-3}\right|<\varepsilon&\iff|9x-3|>\frac8\varepsilon\\&\iff\left|x-\frac13\right|>\frac8{9\varepsilon}.\end{align}If $x\geqslant\dfrac13$, this is equivalent to $x>\dfrac8{9\varepsilon}+\dfrac13$. So, take $N=\max\left\{\dfrac13,\dfrac8{9\varepsilon}+\dfrac13\right\}$, and then$$x>N\implies\left|\frac{x-3}{3x-1}-\frac13\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Minor nitpick:  As $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\frac 8{9\epsilon} > 0$ so $\max(\frac 13, \frac 8{9\epsilon} + \frac 13) = \frac 8{9\epsilon} + \frac 13$.  Which is kind of a nice condition for the OP.  It won't always be this clean.

Answer (score 2):

For these kind of problems,
you don't need to get
the best bound on $x$,
you just need to get a bound
that works for
all large enough $x$.

In this case,
since
$\frac{x-3}{3x-1}-\frac{1}{3}
=\frac{3(x-3)-(3x-1)}{3(3x-1)}
=\frac{-8}{3(3x-1)}
$,
while,
as you wrote,
$x > \frac{8}{9\epsilon} + \frac{1}{3}
$
will work
and is the best bound,
since
$3x-1 > 2x$
for $x > 1$,
then,
for $x > 1$,
$\frac{8}{3(3x-1)}
\lt \frac{8}{3(2x)}
=\frac{4}{3x}
$
so,
for $x > 1$,
$\big|\frac{-8}{3(3x-1)}|
\lt \big|\frac{4}{3x}|
\lt \epsilon$
for
$x > \frac{4}{3\epsilon}
$
and this is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you have to realize with $\epsilon$ $N$ proves is that the actual prove argument goes.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ we magically state a value of $N$ based on $\epsilon$ and then we demonstrate that $x > N \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

To actually start with $\epsilon$ and *derive* the $N$ we must work *backwards* to find the $N$ and we *don't* want to show that one step implies the next step, but instead we want to show that our current step *can* be *implied* ***from*** the next step.

So we want to *end* with $|\frac {x-3}{3x-1} - \frac 13| < \epsilon$.

That will be true if $|\frac {x-3}{3x-1} -\frac 13|=|\frac {-8}{9x-3}|<\epsilon$

So we write $|\frac {x-3}{3x-1} - \frac 13| < \epsilon\Leftarrow |\frac {-8}{9x-3}|<\epsilon$

[Notice the $\Leftarrow$ goes to the *left*.  That means our *conclusion* is implied by the following step.]

Now if $9x-3 > 0$ (or in other words, $x > \frac 13$) then that will be true so

$|\frac {-8}{9x-3}| < \epsilon \Leftarrow x> \frac 13; \frac 8{9x-3} < \epsilon$

$\Leftarrow 0 < \frac 1\epsilon < \frac {9x-3}8 \Leftarrow x > \frac 8{9\epsilon} +\frac 13  >\frac 13$.

And that will be true when $N > \frac 8{9\epsilon} +\frac 13 $ and $x> N$.

And so we want to *START* with $N > \frac 8{9\epsilon} +\frac 13 $.

So that really completes our proof:

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $N$ where $x > N\implies |\frac {x-3}{3x-1}-\frac 13| < \epsilon$ because to find the $N$:

$|\frac {x-3}{3x-1}-\frac 13| < \epsilon\Leftarrow$

$|\frac {-8}{9x-3}|<\epsilon\Leftarrow$

$0 <\frac 1\epsilon <  \frac{9x-3}{8}$ and $x> \frac 13\Leftarrow$

$x > \frac 8{9\epsilon} + \frac 13\Leftarrow$

$N > \frac 8{9\epsilon} + \frac 13$ and $x > N$.

....

Thus we can say with all honesty and conviction.  For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can let $N$ be any number $N > \frac 8{9\epsilon} + \frac 13$.  Then $x> N\implies |\frac {x-3}{3x-1} -\frac 13| < \epsilon$ (just follow the arrows) and that is the very definition of $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac {x-3}{3x-1} = \frac 13$.